# Is there a way to use Log4j for Android without having to write to an external file?

Tags: android, logging, log4j

I'm trying to use `Log4j` along with `android-logging-log4j` in my application.

What I'm trying to achieve is to use `Log4j` to output logs only to logcat until a specific `FileAppender` is attached to the Logger.

This is my `LogConfigurator`.

```
    LogConfigurator configurator = new LogConfigurator();
    configurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "myfile.txt");
    configurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    configurator.configure();

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("MyApplication")
```

The above code works fine.

However if I remove,

`configurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "myfile.txt");`

It throws a FileNotFoundException

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android-log4j.log: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
            at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
            at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
            at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.<init>(FileAppender.java:110)
            at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.<init>(FileAppender.java:121)
            at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.<init>(RollingFileAppender.java:90)
            at de.mindpipe.android.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configureFileAppender(LogConfigurator.java:117)
            at de.mindpipe.android.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:91)
```

I have added both Read and Write External storage permissions in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What file is log4j trying to default to when there is no file specified through the configurator?

Is my approach to this issue wrong ? Or is there any way to get around this ?